# SQL Advanced IIF using MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, iif

Is it possible to use an SQL Query within the logical test of a IIF statement?  I have a staff table that contains all the general staff information one would expect.  One of the fields `IsManager` is a boolean and I use IIF statements to change the output of a query based on if someone has this set to true or not.

The problem I have is when I apply this to a one to many table it is checking if the current record has the IsManager field set true.  I would like it to check if the current person making the query has the field set to true.

```
SELECT TB2.ID, IIF(TB1.IsManager, TB1.LastName, 'Restricted'), IIF(TB1.IsManager, TB1.FirstName, 'Restricted') 
FROM TB1 INNER JOIN TB2 ON TB1.EmployeeNumber = TB2.EmployeeNumber
```

This works if the record I'm checking has `IsManager=True`.  I would like to check the current user for the IIF statement which I do in other Queries using the following

```
SELECT IsManager 
FROM TB1 
WHERE Username=currentUser
```

Where `currentUser` is the VBA variable `Environ("USERNAME")` which is also recorded in the staff details table.

So can I combine these and do an IFF with the above query, something like:

```
SELECT IIF(SELECT IsManager 
FROM TB1 
WHERE Username=currentuser, TB1.LastName, 'Restricted') FROM .... etc etc
```

If not is there an alternative method that I can use that is available to MC Access SQL

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You just need two joins like this

```
SELECT 
  TB2.ID, 
  IIF(AM_I_MANAGER.IsManager, TB1.LastName, 'Restricted'), 
  IIF(AM_I_MANAGER.IsManager, TB1.FirstName, 'Restricted') 
FROM TB1
CROSS JOIN TB1 AS AM_I_MANAGER ON AM_I_MANAGER.Username=currentUser 
JOIN TB2 ON TB1.EmployeeNumber = TB2.EmployeeNumber
```

We use a cross join here because `AM_I_MANAGER.Username=currentUser` will return 1 row.  We then use this one row for every row of the TB1 table (thus the cross join is only "crossing" 1 row).  If that filter returns more than one row you will not get good results.

Comment: I get the following error when running this Syntax error on FROM clause.  Checked the syntax three times and can't see it.

Comment: Apparently MS Access does not use CROSS JOIN

Comment: @iShaymus  -- just take out the "CROSS" should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *DLookup* in your query:

```
PARAMETERS Username Text (255);
SELECT 
    TB2.ID, 
    IIF(DLookup("IsManager", "TB1", "Username = '" & Username & "')"), TB1.LastName, 'Restricted'),
    IIF(DLookup("IsManager", "TB1", "Username = '" & Username & "')"), TB1.FirstName, 'Restricted') 
FROM 
    TB1 
INNER JOIN 
    TB2 
    ON TB1.EmployeeNumber = TB2.EmployeeNumber
```